# How can I type something adjacent to a matrix?

Tags: math-mode

I wanted to type up a matrix with something right next to it. Exactly like in the following picture.

[image]

But I don't know how to get w_1, . . . , w_m. I already used \overset to get the v's. But I am unsure as to how to get the w's.

So far what I have got is

[image]

This was using mathjax as I was typing something on math stackexchange. But how can I get the w's on the left hand side of the matrix?

Comment: You can use blockarray or nicematrix.

Comment: @Sebastiano Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: @Sebastiano Never mind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LaTeX and not MathJax with `kbordermatrix` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
\pazocal{M}(T)=\bordermatrix{
  & v_1 & \ldots & v_k & \ldots & v_n  \cr
w_1 &   &   & A_{1,k} &    \cr
\mkern8mu\vdots &  &   &  \vdots &    \cr
w_m &   &  &  A_{m,k} &   \cr
}.
\]

\end{document}
```